# What build servers does Release Manager 2013 support?

Tags: jenkins, tfs, release-management, devops, ms-release-management

I have been tasked with investigating dev ops for my company's releases. For us, releases consist of deploying many applications, using many different types of technologies. Right now, for simplicity sake, I am currently looking at one team that are developing in Java. They use Jenkins for their automated build deployment. My issue is that I am unable to find much information regarding release manager 2013 and tutorials I do find always say "cross platform/technology development out-of-scope for this tutorial". It is hard for me to see what it actually CAN do (other than microsoft out-of-the-box release/build templates ). I can see TFS 2015 release hub supports jenkens/maven out of the box and quite easily.

What technologies/Build servers is Release Manager 2013 capable hooking into? Is it best to wait until we are upgraded to TFS 2015 to really start digging into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Release Management for Visual Studio 2013 is a continuous delivery
>   solution that automates the release process through all of your
>   environments from TFS through to production, all in one solution, and
>   all integrated with TFS.

Release Management 2013 is not support integrate with Jenkins. More details please refer [Release Management for Visual Studio 2013](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2013/11/25/release-management-for-visual-studio-2013/) and here is the [Release Management 2013 documentation in MSDN Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn217874%28v=vs.120%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

If you are considering starting with Release Management, you should use the new web-based version. If you are already using the server and client version, you should be aware that no new features will be added to this version(Release Management 2013). We encourage you to **move to new web-based version** as soon as possible.

Moreover, here is the tutorial about [Continuous deployment/delivery with Jenkins and VS Team Services](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/05/27/continuous-deploymentdelivery-with-jenkins-and-vs-team-services/)